# Does the number of APIs on Spring JPA Repository affect start-up time?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

From experience, I know having too many named queries in Hibernate hbm XML will cause it to start more slowly as it has to pre-compile them all.

Question:

Will I encounter this same thing if I move my persistence layer to Spring Data JPA Repository and use say, the JpaRespository, which has a ton of APIs that I might not need anyway?

When does Spring Data JPA generate the SQL behind it's repositories?  At start up like Hibernate named queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries are created at runtime, the first time you execute it. The [PartTreeJpaQuery](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/PartTreeJpaQuery.html) creates the associated `CriteriaQuery` and caches it for later reuse.

Your application won't start slower because the Spring `ApplicationContext` doesn't pre-generate the queries at start-up.